# Can anyone help me with an android XML parser?

Tags: android, xml, multithreading, parsing

I don't usualy ask for help, I always do my research and try to find the solutions by myself, but this time I'm really stuck...
I've a lot of experience with some languages, but not with java...
So, what I'm trying to do is an application, that have dynamic layout, and loads it from an XML file on a specific host.
My first problem is that apparently, it's not possible to read the XML from the main thread, so I had to learn about threads and Asynctaks, and I've decided to use a simple thread and store the values in some global variables that I created, but it's not working...
I've also tryed to use SAX for the XML parser, but I prefer DOM.
I'm just trying to do this for more than 3 days, I'm becoming a little mad with this, I hope that someone can help me, here's my code:

This is the class where I'm defining my vars. They are all supposed to handle more than one value, except for the XML one, that will store the URL of the XML to use it in the thread.

```
public class Info {
        public static String Param1[];
        public static String Param2[];
        public static String Param3[];
        public static String Param4[];
        public static String Param5[];
        public static String Param6[];
        public static String XML;
}
```

And here is my main thread:

```
//Create the basic layout
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);
Info.XML="mylink";
Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(Info.XML);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList ActionContainers = doc.getElementsByTagName("ActionContainer");
            Node mainContainer = ActionContainers.item(0);
            Element Container = (Element) mainContainer;
            NodeList Actions = Container.getElementsByTagName("Action");
            for (int i = 0; i < Actions.getLength(); i++) {
                Node mainAction = Actions.item(i);
                Element Action = (Element) mainAction;
                Info.Param1[i]=Action.getAttribute("Param1");
                Info.Param2[i]=Action.getAttribute("Param2");
                Info.Param3[i]=Action.getAttribute("Param3");
                Info.Param4[i]=Action.getAttribute("Param4");
                Info.Param5[i]=Action.getAttribute("Param5");
                Info.Param6[i]=Action.getAttribute("Param6");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Info.XML="Erro";
        }
    }
};
try{
    thread.start();
} catch(Exception e){
    Info.XML="Erro";
}

    EditText et = new EditText(this);
        et.setText(Info.XML);
        ll.addView(et);
        setContentView(sv);
```

No exception is being detected, It simply doesn't return the xml information...
I hope someone can give me a little help here.

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is the XML:

```
<appname Version="yyy" WrittenOn="yyy">
<Config>
    <Page Id="yyy">
        <ActionContainer Id="yyy">
            <Action Param1="xxx" Param2="xxx" Param3="xxx" Param4="xxx" Param5="xxx" Param6="xxx"></Action>
            <Action Param1="xxx" Param2="xxx" Param3="xxx" Param4="xxx" Param5="xxx" Param6="xxx"></Action>
            <Action Param1="xxx" Param2="xxx" Param3="xxx" Param4="xxx" Param5="xxx" Param6="xxx"></Action>
            <Action Param1="xxx" Param2="xxx" Param3="xxx" Param4="xxx" Param5="xxx" Param6="xxx"></Action>
            ...
        </ActionContainer>
    </Page>
</Config>
```

I need all the xxx, and I would like to have them on a multimensional array if possible.

Comment: For completeness, could you edit your answer to include the actual XML you're attempting to parse?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, I've already edited my post with the XML, I hope you can help me :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I'll be the one to answer, since I already need to go to sleep :). But, could you post as much of your Activity as you can? At first glance, I see about 3 possible problematic spots, but I can't be certain which one causes the bug, at the moment.

Comment: In the mainclass, after the thread, I don't have nothing that could be causing problems, but I've already edited too, so that you can see my complete code.

Comment: Check this  [LINK][1]. Here,XML parsing using the sax 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209793/display-data-in-list-view-after-sax-parsing

Answer (score 0):

I still think there's some code missing, but for the sake of not leaving you stranded, here's several things that might be wrong:

- you might not actually get the exception, as `et.setText(Info.XML);` may execute **before** your thread completes, ignoring "ErrNo". My notes on this:

  - possibly there's a bad URL to your XML file (keep in mind that for remote documents you need to have the `INTERNET` permission in your app),
  - the XML you posted is invalid: `<appname>` is not closed and/or there is no root element.
  - you don't seem to initialize the `Info.ParamX` arrays anywhere, which will result in a `NullPointerException`,
  - even if you do initialize them, you're not accounting for the size of `Actions.getLength()`, which might result in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` or similar; in other words, include `Info.ParamX = new String[Actions.getLength()];` before the `for` loop.
  - Other than that, your parsing code seems to work fine. To debug your code properly, either **use the Debug option in ADT**, or **use `System.out.println()` to output the exception in your catch clause, and examine it in LogCat**.
- where's this code located? If it's not in `onCreate()` of your Activity, place it there.

Also, some minor issues:

- try to use [camelBack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) notation for your Java fields and variables, this will make your code more readable for Java programmers.
- using a `Thread` for a throwaway app is OK, but you should avoid it generally, e.g. by replacing it with an `AsyncTask` (which you've read about).

PS. In `ParamX`, `X` is of course every integer from 1 to 6 inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Thread` you should try using `AsyncTask`. See here:

The official android page on threading is quite good
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

this explains it quite well too
http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/

Regarding XML Parsing my app relies on a lot of XML pulled from HTTP requests and I find the SAX parser very good and easy to use once you get it going.

Regarding SAX examples, its been a *long* time since working it out but i found this example in my bookmarks hopefully it helps. Just read the SAX parts
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-android/

hope that helps